# StringToItems в DelphiXE

Tags: delphi

Как правильно заменить знак "!" на Edit ?

Вот так работает:

```
s := StringToItems(s, '!');
```

Делаю вот так:

```
s := StringToItems(s, edit1.text);
```

И получаю ошибку:

> ```
> Incompatible types: 'Char' and 'TCaption'
> ```

Я так понимаю это из-за того что строка состоит из символов....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всё верно - строка состоит из символов. Если функция ожидает на входе один символ, то вы можете сделать вот так:

```
s := StringToItems(s, edit1.text[1]);
```

Comment: Благодарна Вам за подсказку. Именно так и есть, функция ожидает на входе один символ. А параметр [1] дает прочитать этот символ из edit1. Теперь я поняла свою ошибку.